# Regexp matching the smallest possible group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a bit lost with greedy / non-greedy regexp

**I want a regexp that will match the smallest set possible of a mongodb command.**

A mongodb command has this format : `db.collection.command(params)`

I can have multiples commands separated by ";" and / or whitespaces ending or not with ";".

Exemple :

```
db.collection.command(params);db.collection.command(params2) // the regexp must returns db.collection.command(params);
db.collection.command(params);db.collection.command(params2); // the regexp must returns db.collection.command(params); too
```

I tried a lot of things but I didn't find a way to match all my cases.

### So far the best regexp I found is :

```
const commandRegexp = "(db\\.?\\w*?\\.\\w*\\([^]*\\))?;";
const regexp = new RegExp(`${commandRegexp}`);
```

But it does not handle this cases :

```
db.collection.command(params);db.collection.command(params2); // the regexp must returns db.collection.command(params); too
```

The regexp returns `db.collection.command(params);db.collection.command(params2);`, the whole text.

### I need a regexp that will handle all of these :

```
db.collection.command(params) // the regexp must returns db.collection.command(params)
db.collection.command(params);foobar // the regexp must returns db.collection.command(params)
db.collection.command(params); // the regexp must returns db.collection.command(params);
db.collection.command(params);db.collection.command(params2) // the regexp must returns db.collection.command(params)
db.collection.command(params);db.collection.command(params2); // the regexp must returns db.collection.command(params)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested with https://regex101.com

`/(db\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\(([^)]+)\)(;|$))/i`

Comment: Great,thx !! I just had to change the matching group like this `/(db\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\([^)]+\))(;|$)/i;`. Can you update your answer with it, and I accept it.